# Discord.js Bot Database Won't Show

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, discord.js

So, I've forked this repl from another https://replit.com/@AryWiz/EconomyBot?v=1

And in the code, there is something called work.js. It generates a new job for you to do everytime you run it. I've searched the entire project, and there is nothing that has the data workedAs, which I think has all the jobs listed in it, yet it still generates a job. I want to edit the list, but there is nowhere to edit it

I searched for any file that might contain that code, but no file did

Comment: Have you tried searching the project for a specific string matching the value of `workedAs`? For example, if you see `You worked as a dairy farmer`, try searching for `dairy farmer`. Be sure to search the hidden files as well - from what I've seen of your repl (`work.js`), `workedAs` is a key of `work`, which is within `eco`, and when searching for `eco`, I've come accross `quick.db` and `quick.eco` inside the `node modules`.

Comment: I've tried that, but when I search a specific string nothing comes up. In quick.db and quick.eco I can't find it either.

Comment: What about the SQLite database? Is anything stored there?

Comment: The`SQLite` database only stores cooldown values and part of the `shop.js` command. The only thing related to `work.js` is the command cooldown